# Where do you put the reward you gain when attacking Draco/zombies?

Tags: vikings-gone-wild

When you attack a zombie or Draco, you earn some ressources.

Do you store them immediately (or on the Town hall building if you don't have storage room)?
Do they stay "somewhere in your gaming zone" (for instance witht he units you used to attack) waiting for the storage phase to be added to the storage building?

The latter would mean than no-one can get them by attacking you or by stealing them...

Sorry if I don't use the correct wording for game elements, I have the French version of the rules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the answer straight from the Publisher [on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1703418/where-do-you-put-reward-you-gain-when-attacking-dr):

> If you have a container, straight there. If you don't it goes on top of your Town Hall and has to be used this turned otherwise you will have to discard it!
>   Indeed, it means that this resource is vulnerable to an attack this turn. Unless you have a defense and that could be a nice lure